# How do I programmatically set data source for ASP.NET ReportViewer control?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

How do I programmatically set the data source for the ASP.NET ReportViewer control?

I have a VS 2008 ReportViewer control and want to switch between a couple of different reports.

I can switch reports by setting the report source and refreshing the control, but I can't see where to set the data source.

Each report has its own data source, and if I configure them initially when the control is built it is fine, but I need to switch between them.

Comment: Are you talking about the ReportViewer control, or some other control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the question is about ReportViewer control.

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsname", source));
```

`"dsname"` is the name of the data source, you can find it .rdlc file. `source` is the variable with data you want to show in the report.

Comment: When I I do this I get
"# An error has occurred during report processing.

    * A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source ...."

Comment: And the supplied data source listed in the data source for the default report that I originally setup. It is like the new data source is not really being set.

Comment: I am still looking at this. Wondering if I have the wrong "source name". How do I see the source used in the report?

Comment: I found the source name in the main aspx page not in the report.

Answer (score 1):

1) Basic markup:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptView" Width="1000px" ProcessingMode="Local"
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" runat="server"  >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

2) Edit the report XML. Set up your dataset & field names:

```
<DataSets>
  <DataSet Name="dsSource">
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="MyField1">
        <DataField>MyField1</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
    <Query>
      <DataSourceName>dsSource</DataSourceName>
      <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
    </Query>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

3) Set datasource on both report & report viewer (don't know why...both are necessary)

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProc", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

cn.Open();
da.Fill(tbl);
cn.Close();

rptView.Visible = true;
rptView.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource rptData = new ReportDataSource("dsSource", tbl);

LocalReport r = new LocalReport();
r.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MyReport.rdlc");
r.DataSources.Add(rptData);

rptView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptData);
rptView.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MyReport.rdlc");
rptView.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalReportViewer.AsyncRendering = True
    If Session.Count > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To Session.Count - 1
            If Session(i).GetType().ToString() = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy" Then
                Session.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    GlobalReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = ""
GlobalReportViewer.LocalReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain()
GlobalReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("XXXDataSet_YYYTable", "ObjectDSZZZ"))
GlobalReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports\AAAReport.rdlc"
GlobalReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh()
```