# ASP.NET/VB.NET Generating RDLC gives Useless Error of just the Dataset Name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

I've tried just about every different code example of programmatically generating a PDF from an RDLC report. Every single one gives me the generic "An error occurred during local report processing" on the Render step. When I check the inner exception, I get the most useless error ever, the name of my dataset: "Dataset1". That's it. I'm running the web app locally and using the connection string from the website for the report. The report uses a single table as the source. It's about as vanilla as can be. Here's one example of the code that generates the error, but I've tried many other similar examples with the same resulting error.

```
    Dim rv As New ReportViewer
    Dim warnings As Warning()
    Dim streamids As String()
    Dim mimeType As String
    Dim encoding As String
    Dim filenameExtension As String

    Try
        rv.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/MyReport.rdlc"

        Dim bytes As Byte() = rv.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, filenameExtension, streamids, warnings)

        Using fs As New FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create)
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: RDLC needs a datasource. From your code there is nowhere you set up the datasource to the report. The datasource name/key is expected to be "DataSet1"

Comment: If I open the RDLC and right-click on DataSet1, the Data source is set. Do I need to do it again in my code?

Comment: Also, when I preview data on the DataSource, data is returned.

Comment: I debugged the code and found you are correct, it appears there are no data sources on the rv.LocalReport. I found this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263566/how-do-i-programmatically-set-data-source-for-asp-net-reportviewer-control Seems stupid to have to re-specify this when I already did it once in the report, but oh well.